# datetimepicker minDate issue

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am setting `minDate` and `maxDate` on datetimepicker.

`minDate` is showing as selectable but when I click it, it does not update the input control.
Selecting `maxDate` works fine.

Here is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/zlaja1983/t23z4hLd/

```
var minDate = moment().subtract(7, 'days');
var maxDate = moment();
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  minDate: minDate,
  maxDate: maxDate,
  showClear: false,
  useCurrent: false,
  format: 'l'
});
```

Comment: The fiddle seems to work just as expected, today and the previous seven days are selectable, the other days aren't? It's actually somewhat suprising, as you'd think that passing Moment objects would cause issues, and that you'd have to do `minDate.toDate()` to get the actual date objects, but it does seem to work.

Comment: I think that you can solve this issue upgrading the datetimepicker to the lastest version (**4.17.42**), while in your fiddle you are using **4.14.30**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the plugin. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjwilly16/6kwore8b/2/).

For some reason, this works...

```
var minDate = moment().subtract(7, 'days').millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0);
```

Found the solution on their [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1832).

**Edit:** Just realized that you're the same person who opened the issue on Github. Haha.